# Flutter Podfile not created correctly

Tags: ios, flutter, podfile

I created a new flutter project. This is my pubspec.yaml file:

```
name: app_name
description: App Name

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.1 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_bloc: ^7.3.1
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  get_it: ^7.1.3
  floor: ^1.2.0
  flutter_speed_dial: ^5.0.0+1

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
  floor_generator: ^1.2.0
  build_runner: ^2.1.2

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/logo.png"

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  module:
    androidX: true
    androidPackage: com.example.appname
    iosBundleIdentifier: com.example.appname
```

When I run the following commands:

`flutter pub get`
`pod init`
`pod install`

The podfile is created, but only with the following contents:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Runner' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Runner

end
```

When I try to run the app, I get the following error:
`The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation`

Anyone knows how I can fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem as you. Do have you solved it yet?

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I have the same issue

Comment: No, I didn't :/

Answer (score 2):

First clear Derived data from preference and remove it from bin as well
then use following commands

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub get`
3. `cd ios`
4. `pod install`
5. `pod update`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Did not work though

Comment: Does anyone get solution on same . i. am facing same issue